# Handling Uncommitable transaction SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, try-catch, xact-abort

I have a procedure which is of the below sort

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
...transactins A....
   BEGIN TRY
   .... Transaction B ....
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
   .... Set variables and print messages ....
   END CATCH
....Transaction C
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN
...Transaction D
END CATCH
```

The Transaction B is throwing an error and due to this the process is going into an uncommitable state and throwing the below error. I have checked the XACT_STATE() Value it is -1

> Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xxxxxxxx, Line 70
> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

Is there any other way to over come this by some how skipping the transaction B and executing the transactions C

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using a transaction is that the operations within it either all succeed or all fail. If you want to isolate `Transaction C` from the affects of the failure of `Transaction B`, then use separate `BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK` operations for each.

Comment: I saw somwwhere in the wesites that nested transactions could help. But i am not able to implement it. Do you have any idea in realation to this ???

Comment: One key point regarding nested transactions, from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx), "Committing inner transactions is ignored by the SQL Server Database Engine. The transaction is either committed or rolled back based on the action taken at the end of the outermost transaction. If the outer transaction is committed, the inner nested transactions are also committed. If the outer transaction is rolled back, then all inner transactions are also rolled back, regardless of whether or not the inner transactions were individually committed."

Comment: Generally speaking you can create a save point and roll back to that though but obviously not when your transaction is in a doomed state.